# Why this statement rs=st.executeQuery(query); is not excuting?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Why is this query `rs=st.executeQuery(query)`; not executed to select a table from database?

```
  String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
  if (gender != null) {
  String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";

  String query ="select username,password from "+table+" where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";

  rs=st.executeQuery(query);  //Why This statement having error
  }
```

**Mysql Query** for this table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJtf.jpg)i think this query is wrong

```
 "select username,password from "+table+" where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";
```

I have two tables one is for the teacher and one is for students both have all same columns with same data type.

How can I select table from mysql database to get login. I have two tables one is for student and one is for teacher if user select teacher, radio button and enter username and password if user username and password equals to mysql database username and password he will get login same case is for student if he select student radio but and enter username and password if username, password equals to student table of mysql username, password he will get login.

**Why this query is not executed to select a table**

`rs=st.executeQuery(query);`

**image of error coming**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSWSm.jpg)  //error

**index.jsp**

```
 <form  method="GET " action="statement.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 

 <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
 <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password" /> 

 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student

 <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
 </form>
```

**statement.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
 <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
 <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
 <%@page  import=" java.sql.SQLException" %>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

 <%@include file="db conn.jsp" %>
 <% 
 String name=request.getParameter("username");
 String abc=request.getParameter("password");       

 String gender = request.getParameter("gender");

 if (gender != null) {
 String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";

 String query ="select username,password from "+table+" where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";

   rs=st.executeQuery(query);  //Why This statement having error
  }
    if(rs.next()) 
   {
    response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");
   }
   else
   {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
  %>
```

**db conn.jsp**  // For database connection

```
  <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
  <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
  <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
  <%
    Connection c1 = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher","root", "abcde");
    {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
    System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
    System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

    st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
    {
    System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
     }
    if (c1!= null) {
    System. out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
     } else {
    System.out.println("We should never get here.");
    }}
  %>
```

**error**

```
 HTTP Status 500 -
 type Exception report
 message
 description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
 exception

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /statement.jsp:29

 26:    String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
 27:    // replace dots with your values
 28:     String query ="select * from " +table+ "where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";
 29:     st.executeQuery(query); 
 30:
```

**Stacktrace:**

`org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)`

Why this query doesn't select a table from mysql database. I have two tables in mysql one is student and other is teacher2 both have the same column with same data type. If user select radio button of the student then then the student table username and password would be shown if user select teacher, radio button, then teacher2 username and password would be shown to get a login

Comment: It looks like you are missing spaces around the keywords.

Comment: Please use a prepared statement. Makes the code easier to read and run...

Comment: That is obviously not SQL problem. Check your `table` and `query` variables before the execution. BTW: It is nice to have genders as "teacher" and "student"

Comment: @SlavaMurygin [enter image description here][1]    `"select username,password from " +table+ " where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";` Why is not working?

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code? You have to look at values of your variables during the execution. Also, you did not provide your error. Do you have one? Maybe you just do not have a person with password in your table.

Comment: Ever heard of an SQL injection attack? Once you figure out your problem, follow @rabbitguy 's advice and convert it to use prepared statements. Otherwise, hacker's will gladly take over your servers and steal all your data and do other dirty rotten things to make you cry.

Comment: :-) Do not make it complicated. Don't you see it is a student.

Comment: This thing is full of SQL injection holes and you're using plain-text passwords. Seriously? **Stop**. Find an authentication system that fits your needs and is documented and tested. What you're doing here is outrageous and reckless.

Answer (score 1):

in your string concatenations, you forgot to put spaces at the end of some worde like

```
'from'+ table //'fromteacher2'
```

a good way to prevent this from happening in queries is to use PreparedStatements. It's good practice to use them when dealing with variables.You can use PreparedStatements like this:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
public class Foo(){
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //see code above, skipping initialisation
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username,password FROM ? where username= ? AND password= ?");
        pst.setString(1, table);
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(1, abc);
        pst.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

conclusion, you just have a simple syntax error in your SQLquery which can be solved by adding the spaces, or by using (it's good practice, just do it) PreparedStatements

Comment: What will be the jsp code of my code where im wrong ? i think in sql query im wrong and here `rs=st.executeQuery(query);` im wrong

Comment: the error is where you append your stings together. You have "from"+table which will result in "fromteacher2" you must type "from " +table so you have spaces between your words. Better is to use the PreparedStatement i put in my example, you can just copy paste it instead of your rows 28 and 29 (what's inside the main function in the last code part from my answer)

Comment: in your image you have other code then you are pasting here, so i'll get another look at he posted code you have here

Comment: What is wrong in it? `"select username,password from "+table+" where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";`

Comment: in the picture you posted you did not have the spacing behind from, and the error in the picture is from that syntax error. What's wrong about your query is that it's vulnerable to SQL injection, using PreparedStatements is already safer (not shure how safe tough). Can you update your image to the error from the new code?

Comment: please also post your previous prepareStatement code thanks.

Comment: it was the code you have in conn.jsp but you hadn't posted that file back then yet. (you can view it if you press on _edited X days ago_